# Python OpenCV.remap/undistort cut the image

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I try to implement [Camera calibration](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html) from OpenCV python site. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import glob

CHECKERBOARD = (8,6)
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

objp = np.zeros((CHECKERBOARD[0]*CHECKERBOARD[1],3), np.float32) #[56][3]
# (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:CHECKERBOARD[0],0:CHECKERBOARD[1]].T.reshape(-1,2)

objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

# images like *.jpg
lastImageWithPattern = None # last image with pattern recognize
images = glob.glob('*.jpg')
for fname in images:
    img = cv.imread(fname) #read image
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #black and white

    # find corners
    # ret: are there corners, corners: corners coordinates
    ret, corners = cv.findChessboardCorners(gray,(CHECKERBOARD[0],CHECKERBOARD[1]), None)
    if ret == True:
        lastImageWithPattern = fname
        print("Found pattern in " + fname)
        # fix corners coordinates
        corners2 = cv.cornerSubPix(gray,corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
    
        # save corners coordinate
        objpoints.append(objp)
        imgpoints.append(corners)

if lastImageWithPattern is not None:
    # Camera calibration
    # return: is OK calib, camera matrix, distortion,rotation vector, translation vector
    ret, matrix, distortion, r_vecs, t_vecs = cv.calibrateCamera( objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)

    img = cv.imread(lastImageWithPattern)
    h,w = img.shape[:2] # размерите на изображението
    newCameraMatrix, roi = cv.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(matrix, distortion, (w,h),1,(w,h))

    #fix distortion
    mapx, mapy = cv.initUndistortRectifyMap(matrix, distortion, None, newCameraMatrix, (w,h), 5)
    dst = cv.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv.INTER_LINEAR)

    # Crop image
    x,y,w,h = roi
    dst = dst[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv.imwrite('calibResult.jpg', dst)
```

I use 10 photos. For example here I will show only one image. Problem with the result is same if you use only this image:
[image: There is blur because this is not my house]

In the end of script I expect image with fixed distortion and maybe some missing pixsels but not almost all of them. It this case my result image(calibResult.jpg) is:

[image]

Result is the same if I use **cv.undistort** from the same titorial.
I want to know why image is so cut and maybe more distorted.

My code work OK when I use samples/data/left01.jpg – left14.jpg and maybe something in my images is not OK but I don't know what and how to debug it.

Comment: Start with confirming the result of each steps.
e.g. "Chess Board recognition is OK?", "calibration result is OK?", "`newCameraMatrix` is OK?", ...

Comment: I don't remember where I saw the answer but there is similar [here][https://answers.opencv.org/question/28438/undistortion-at-far-edges-of-image/]: `make sure the edges are well represented by the checkerboard in your calibration images`. Result is bad because there is not enough images at the edges of the image.